# multi-class classification with f1 score equal to 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, precision-recall

[image]I'm dealing with a multi-class classification, and at the end, for some of the labels, the F1 score and precision and recall are 1 .
Is It normal?

I thought it was odd and searched it out, but the answers were quite different and said it was okay.

As u can see in the pic the accuracy is 88 % and I balanced the data, used PCA, scaled with a min-max scaler, and used Grid searchCV for cross-validation.  The data set is real-world data and only has 62 rows, the problem is about predicting depression in the 3rd Trimester of pregnancy using features like (dep and anxiety in the 1st and 2nd Trimester.....)

Answer (score 0):

This means that your model fits the training data perfectly. Is it likely that your data can be predicted to this degree of accuracy?
Are you using a balanced dataset so that there is enough variance and will your model do well in the real world? Your model may be overfitting.

Comment: As u can see in the pic the accuracy is 88 % and I balanced the data, used PCA, scaled with a min-max scaler, and used Grid searchCV for cross-validation.  The data set is real-world data and only has 62 rows, the problem is about predicting depression in the 3rd Trimester of pregnancy using features like (dep and anxiety in the 1st and 2nd Trimester.....)

Comment: What does each class label represent?

Comment: 0 means normal 1 mild depression 2 moderate 3 severe depression

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use a probability score rather than a discrete True/False. If your threshold is set to 50% then both 51% and 99% will be classed as positive. You can use this function in sk-learn: predict_proba.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).